# validating EditText input

Tags: android

Trying to confirm that an EditText tool is not empty when the user clicks a button. Whenever the EditText is not blank the code works. But whenever it is blank my program crashes. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
if (et1.getText().toString() != null) {   

     inpt_weight = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString()); 
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "weight is not null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 


      } else { 

        inpt_weight = 0;
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "weight is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

      };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its trying to parse an empty string("") to an integer which is not possible
try:

```
if (!et1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("") && et1.getText().toString() != null)
```

Comment: yep I would add && !et1.getText().toString().equals("") to your if statement.  Also if you are looking for strict number input you might remove all ' ' incase they had hit space.

Comment: Thats it. You guys are great. Thanks so much. I spent all day beating on that!

Answer (score 1):

This will be a good way:

```
if(et1.getText().toString().trim().length()==0){
 Log.d("No data","No text found in the edit text");
}
```

This also checks if the user had put nothing but only spaces.

In your code, I see you're converting the text to numbers.
In this case, either put correct IMEMethod for the edit text so that it takes only numbers, or check in your code that user has entered only numeric characters, else you'll end up with a NumberFormatException while conversion if the user has entered non numeric characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code please..

```
if(et1.getText().toString().equals("")){
Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "weight is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
else{
  inpt_weight = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString()); 
  Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "weight is not null & it is : "+inpt_weight,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```